# why preferredContentSize doesn't work when presenting UIViewController with PresentationStyle = .formSheet

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller

I just try to test the `preferredContentSize` effect with code below:

```
let vc = CustomViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width:50, height: 50)
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

But it seems that the `preferredContentSize` property doesn't work at all. I can definitely sure that "CustomViewController" have no side effect on this problem because it's an empty UIViewController subclass.

According to the official docs:

> In a regular-width, regular-height size class, the system adds a dimming layer over the background content and centers the view controller’s content on top of this layer. The default content size is smaller than that of the UIModalPresentationStyle.pageSheet style. A part of the background content always remains visible.
> To provide a custom content size, use the modal view controller’s preferredContentSize property.

I've found a lot of similar questions, but nearly all of them are about presenting with popover. My question is whether `preferredContentSize` only works with `.popover` style, or `.formSheet` style either.

And if it works with `.formSheet` style presentation, what's wrong with my code? Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you override the `preferredContentSize` property in your `CustomViewController` class instead of trying to set the size as you are now? And confirm you are doing this on an iPad.

Comment: The “regular-width, regular-height size class” only applies to iPad (in non-split view or  multitasking).

Comment: @Geoff Hackworth It seems that it only works on iPad, the size class takes effect. thank you.

Comment: @HangarRash yes, it seems that the size class takes effect.